# Create a Dataframe from the Mbox Data with Email Contents

Tags: python, email, mbox

I use mbox library to read mbox data (email data I downloaded with google takeout) with Python but I can not find how I can read the body of the email.

Below are the headers, I couldn't find anything related to text written in the email

```
mbox[0].keys()



['X-GM-THRID',
 'X-Gmail-Labels',
 'Delivered-To',
 'Received',
 'X-Received',
 'ARC-Seal',
 'ARC-Message-Signature',
 'ARC-Authentication-Results',
 'Return-Path',
 'Received',
 'Received-SPF',
 'Authentication-Results',
 'DKIM-Signature',
 'X-Google-DKIM-Signature',
 'X-Gm-Message-State',
 'X-Google-Smtp-Source',
 'X-Received',
 'MIME-Version',
 'From',
 'Date',
 'Message-ID',
 'Subject',
 'To',
 'Cc',
 'Content-Type']
```

How can I extract body of the email with python?